# Difference in text between Linux and OSX in when using Batik to SVG convert SVG to PNG

Tags: java, linux, svg, mozilla, batik

When I run the same code in Linux environment and try to convert svg to png using batik the position of text is shifted.

The same code in OSX is giving the correct png. It seems that in Linux the position of all text-elements are shifting right.

***Linux***:

[image: Resulting image in Linux]

***OS X***:

[image: Resulting image in OSX]

Why is the image wrong on Linux?

---

Here is the code:

```
TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(svgPath);
// define OutputStream to PNG Image and attach to TranscoderOutput
OutputStream ostream = null;
File tempOutputFile = File.createTempFile(svgPath, ".png");
tempOutputFile.deleteOnExit();
try {
    ostream = new FileOutputStream(tempOutputFile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(ostream);
// create a JPEG transcoder
PNGTranscoder t = new PNGTranscoder();
// set the transcoding hints
// convert and write output
t.transcode(input, output);
// flush and close the stream then exit
ostream.flush();
ostream.close();
return tempOutputFile;
```

***SVG file***:

```svg
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- Created with SVG-edit - https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit-->

  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <rect display-height="NaN" display-width="NaN" display-y="125.5" display-x="65.25" rect-id="0" id="svg_1" height="194" width="316" y="115" x="129" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
  <text alignment-baseline="text-before-edge" xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="serif" font-size="24" id="svg_2" y="125.5" x="65.25" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000">sssssss</text>

</svg>
```

Comment: You need to add more details to your question, screenshot..how to reproduce etc.

Comment: What's in the SVG file?

Comment: i m not able to getting what is actual reason . but most probably i m thinking about font problem because all things is working fine in mac and window system . you can see attached image

Comment: hey @SufiyanGhori you can see i attached image also

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'm not sure exactly what result you are trying to achieve. The two screenshots, and the snippet embedded in the question, all display something different.  Are you trying to have the end of the text coincide with the left hand side of the rectangle?

There are several potential issues going on here:

1. You aren't using the same font in all environments. You can tell that from the screenshots. "sans-serif" won't necessarily end up being the same font in different operating systems. Especially so if the same exact font isn't installed on both.
2. Even with the exact same font, different font rendering engines, render text slightly differently.  You won't necessarily get pixel-perfect positioning.
3. I may be wrong, but I suspect Batik probably doesn't support `alignment-baseline`. So that will affect your text positioning.
4. If you want the end of a piece of text to coincide exactly with some point, then use `text-anchor="end"` to make the text right-justified.  See below.

```html
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect id="svg_1" height="194" width="316" y="115" x="129" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
  <text text-anchor="end" font-family="serif" font-size="24" id="svg_2" y="115" x="129" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000">Exact corner</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: The [support table for batik](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/status.html) does indicate that alignment-baseline is not supported.

Comment: Thanks for checking that Robert.